# Appearance of Client Names

Tags: wordpress, civireport

Why do some of the names entered show up as firstnamelastname and others as last name, first name on my reports?

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you add the CMS you are using and which version of CiviCRM you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide on which reports you getting them different? Normally the contacts sort name is used to display on all reports. The way it need to be stored is defined in Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> [Display Preference](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1).

Answer (score 1):

They will appear in your report in the way the data is stored in the database. You may need to clarify what you have to get a better answer. But I would expect that if in your report you have

- peterdavis and
- Jones, Mary

showing, then that suggests your data itself needs sorting, maybe someone did a strange import?

Comment: It was strange.  We entered the names manually as a test - we thought all the same way.  Then, in the same report (didn't matter which report) the names would appear in all mixed formats.  Anyhow - we have resolved it by adjusting the "formula" in the admin section and re-setting all the names.  Thanks for the feedback though!